Port Forward routing; Java applet from client does not connect
Hi I have a remote router with public IP and a device (not a PC) on the lan of the router with private IP 192.168.1.3.
The device has embedded web server so I set up a port forward rule in the router and can reach the devices configuration pages on port 80 using  from browser. That all works fine. There is a real time activity log option this is using Java.
In the LAN enviroment ie my laptop connected directly to device ..I click the activity log option and a small file is downloaded to my PC here's part of it opened in notepad.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- href attribute contains relative path;
     codebase attribute not specified -->
 <jnlp spec="6.0+" 
codebase="http://192.168.1.3"
     href="jnlp/LogViewer.jnlp">
     <information>
    <title>Activity Log Viewer</title>

When I execute this file the application loads and I can log in.
When I do the same on the remote router It downloads this file to my laptop  but it does not launch and java times out with connection error. I did try changing the lan address(192.168.1.3 in this .jnlp to the public IP of the remote router but it does not connect.
When testing this on the LAN I ran wireshark and it always use port 80 on the device but yet does not work remotely even though port 80 is forwarded.
What must I do in the router to allow this to work?
Thank you.

That's quite confusing ;) You'll learn more though if you run javaws http://192.168.1.3 at the command line

Sorry explained best I could this is is a routing issue moreso

It downloads this file to my laptop but it does not launch The obvious question, but .. do you have javaws on that box?

I have Java run time enviroment on my laptop that opens the file

Well should open it normally  but across WAN does not  on LAN works fine

If there's a web interface on the router, is it listening on port 80? I'm a little doubtful from your description

Port forward is  setup on the remote  router now ..when I type the  public IP address Iinto a brorswer I am brought directly to the lan device GUI page from where I click activity logger and the file is download but again the jnlp file does not connect .

You're not answering my question (which was specific). I don't want to be making assumptions.

There is a web interface on the router. Currently reachable on port 443 as port 80 diverts.

OK so it diverts to another web server (it would have to). Then what do you get when you access http://192.168.1.3 in your browser?

thlks your  input but clearly you cannot solve with generic replies Mods can close this I spent enough time time wiresharking this and tracert to see ip address forwarding to the public IP of my router about 8 ip address

I'm not giving "generic replies". I'm trying to ascertain exactly what's going on. Your jnlp URL is using the default port (80). afaics so is your router. That's going to be a problem. What you should probably do is run the webserver that's serving the jnlp on a different port. Then forwarding is going to be possible

I have no access to underlying code on the jnlp webserver so that would not be possible.

Glad to hear it. What did you do?

I was mistaken .I had hooked up that device with the webserver locally on my Lan to do further tests. I noted that port 10130 was also in play so I added a forwarding rule for that on the remote router and tested again but I had not removed the lan connected device and it diverted to it and opened the application. When I removed the locally connected lan device I found I was back to square 1!
